# Deciphering a qwert cipher

Tags: c, encryption

I am having trouble reversing this code to decrypt back to abc from qwerty.

I don't know where to start.
I tried to replace index with a string containing ABC... 
I also tried swapping the ciphertext to abc and changing the the index to qwerty with no avail.

This is the original code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char* ciphertext = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";    // cipher lookup

    char input[500];                                    // input buffer
    printf("Enter text: ");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);                 // safe input from user
    input[strlen(input) - 1] = 0;                       // remove the \n (newline)
    int count = strlen(input);                          // get the string length

    char output[count];                                 // output string
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {                    // loop through characters in input
        int index = ((int) input[i]) - 97;              // get the index in the cipher by subtracting 'a' (97) from the current character
        if(index < 0) {
            output[i] = ' ';                            // if index < 0, put a space to account for spaces
        }
        else {
            output[i] = ciphertext[index];              // else, assign the output[i] to the ciphertext[index]
        }
    }
    output[count] = 0;                                  // null-terminate the string

    printf("output: %s\n", output);                     // output the result
}
```

My efforts have done nothing and it just reprints what I entered

Comment: Fyi, `output[count] = 0;` = out of range write.

Comment: `"kxvmcnophqrszyijadlegwbuft"` - you can do it on paper. Or loop the string until you find a match.

Answer (score 2):

So you started with 'a' (ascii 97) and converted that to an index into an array of characters via `char_value - 97`

To convert back to plaintext you need to go from `q` to `a`.

One way would be search `ciphertext` to find the index your character (q) appears at and then add 97 to that index to get the original value.